# Python function to populate multiple tables in PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have a class with multiple functions and in, almost, everyone of them I have to populate different QTableWidgets. **I would like to make a function that given a tables name, headers and data populates the said table.**

This is working (but static and works just for one table "tableParada"):

```
header = ['Horario teórico', 'Entrada a terminal', 'Salida de terminal', 'Tiempo parcial en terminal']
self.ui.tableParada.setRowCount(cantidadFilas)
self.ui.tableParada.setColumnCount(len(header))
self.ui.tableParada.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(header)

for columnas in range(cantidadFilas):
    self.ui.tableParada.setItem(columnas, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(tiempoTeoricoTerminal[columnas])))
    self.ui.tableParada.setItem(columnas, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(tiempoInicioTerminal[columnas].time())))
    self.ui.tableParada.setItem(columnas, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(tiempoFinTerminal[columnas].time())))
    self.ui.tableParada.setItem(columnas, 3, QTableWidgetItem(str(tiempoEnTerminal[columnas])))
```

This is what I came up with (and does not work):

```
def completarTabla(tabla, headerFila, headerColumna, datos):
    """Completado automático de tabla tipo QTableWidget."""
    tabla.setRowCount(len(headerFila))
    tabla.setColumnCount(len(headerColumna))
    tabla.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headerColumna)
    tabla.setVerticalHeaderLabels(headerFila)

    for fila in range(len(headerFila)):
        for columna in range(len(headerColumna)):
            tabla.setItem(fila, columna, QTableWidgetItem(str(datos[fila][columna])))
```

The problem is when I call the function:

```
headerColumna = ['Horario teórico', 'Entrada a terminal', 'Salida de terminal', 'Tiempo parcial en terminal']
headerFila = []
completarTabla('tableParada', headerFila, headerColumna, tiempo)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/TIC/Dropbox/TransBus - La Estrella/Programación/control-de-tiempo/query.py", line 362, in queryParada
completarTabla('tableParada', headerFila, headerColumna, tiempo)
File "C:/Users/TIC/Dropbox/TransBus - La Estrella/Programación/control-de-tiempo/query.py", line 659, in completarTabla
tabla.setRowCount(len(headerFila))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setRowCount'
```

I know that I am passing a str to the function and then the replacement does not work, if I pass the table name (tableParada) it also does not work. Then:

- What should I pass to the function for it to work?
- Is there another method?
- Is it even possible?

Sorry but I'm new on Python + PyQt, object oriented programming, also this is my first post on stackoverflow and english is not my mother tongue. I just really would like to make it in a right way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try passing `tableParada` instead of `'tableParada'` (that is, the actual `tableParada` object instead of a string representing its name)?  Or perhaps `self.ui.tableParada` if that is how you're accessing it?

Comment: I did, as I posted, but what I did not try was: **self.ui.tableParada**. That work perfectly (meaning I have a new error on the next line, but that is a problem on the way I defined the parameters on my function). Thanks a lot! EDIT: I cannot select your answer, should I edit the original post to include the solution? Sorry, really really new on this!

Comment: I added an answer with that info that you can accept if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing `self.ui.tableParada` instead of the string `'tableParada'`.  You need to pass the actual widget object.